# Find the Maximum Likelihood estimator for $r$

Tags: statistics, self-learning, maximum-likelihood

I have a set of data

$$X \sim N_2(0,\Sigma) \quad \text{with} \quad \Sigma = \pmatrix{ \sigma^2 & r\sigma^2 \\ r\sigma^2 & \sigma^2}$$

and I am asked to find the Maximum Likelihood estimates of $r$.

Firstly I find the log likelihood of my data which is

$$-n\log(2\pi) - 2n\log(\sigma) - \frac{n}{2} \log(1-r^2) - \frac{1}{2\sigma^2(1-r^2)}\sum_i (x_{i1}^2 - 2rx_{i1}x_{i2} + x_{i2}^2)$$

Then I want to differentiate this w.r.t. to $r$ which gives

$$-\frac{n}{2}\bigg(\frac{-2r}{1-r^2}\bigg) - \frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\bigg(\frac{2r}{(1-r^2)^2}\bigg)\sum_i (x_{i1}^2 - 2rx_{i1}x_{i2} + x_{i2}^2) - \frac{1}{2\sigma^2(1-r^2)}\sum_i -2x_{i1}x_{i2}$$

Now the question says show that the MLE for $r$ is given as

$$\hat r = 2\frac{\sum_i x_{i1}x_{i2}}{\sum_i (x_{i1}^2 + x_{i2}^2)}$$

but I can't seem to get to this. Can someone please put me out of my misery. I've spent far too long on this.

Edit: I had some mistypes. It's $x_{i2}^2$ **not** $2x_{i2}^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the log-likelihood as
$$
\ell(r,\sigma^2)=-\frac{n}{2}\log(1-r^2)-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\frac{1}{1-r^2}\left(A-2rB\right) - n\log\sigma^2,
$$
where
$$
A = \sum_{i}x_i^2+y_i^2, \qquad B\sum_{i}x_iy_i.
$$
Then $\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial r}=0$ implies that
$$
nr\sigma^2+\frac{1}{1-r^2}\left((r^2+1)B - Ar \right) =0 \tag{1}.
$$
Also $\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial \sigma^2} = 0$ further implies
$$
n\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{2(1-r^2)}\left(A - 2rB\right)  \tag{2}.
$$
Put $(2)$ into $(1)$ to get 
\begin{align}
\frac{r}{2(1-r^2)}\left(A-2rB \right) + \frac{1}{1-r^2}\left((r^2+1)B - Ar \right) = 0,
\end{align}
or
$$
rA - 2r^2B + 2r^2B + 2B - 2Ar = 0 \iff r=\frac{2B}{A}.
$$

---

Couple more details on the derivation of $(1)$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial r}&=n\frac{r}{1-r^2} - \frac{1}{\sigma^2}\frac{r}{(1-r^2)^2}\left[ A-2rB \right] + \frac{1}{\sigma^2(1-r^2)}B \\
&=\frac{1}{\sigma^2(1-r^2)}\left(nr\sigma^2 +\frac{1}{1-r^2}\left[2r^2B - rA\right] + \frac{1-r^2}{1-r^2}B\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{\sigma^2(1-r^2)}\left(nr\sigma^2 + \frac{1}{1-r^2}\left[ (r^2 + 1)B + rA\right]\right).
\end{align}